# How to implement Telegram bot as a widget on your website?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, tdlib

I'm trying to create some sort of **live chat widget**, but with a Telegram bot instead of a real person on the other side. I don't know if it is possible, but ideally, there is a chat window that can be implemented on a website, and establishes a new connection with a telegram bot once you click on it. The end-user should **NOT have a Telegram account**. I already tried to implement [Intergram](https://github.com/idoco/intergram) but it's not exactly what I'm looking for, as it merely forwards the message to a human using webhooks, and the bot is only used as a message broker. I have heard that some customization is possible using [tdlib](https://github.com/tdlib/td) but I'm not sure if it can help me achieve the desired result.

How should I start implementing a chat window with my bot on a website?

Answer (score 0):

They would need an account to my knowledge to interact, unless you are using a premade bot as you mention such as Intergram. I would use slack instead.